# python file without extension works, but with .py extension fails to import my module

Tags: python

My python file has "from .. import" statement to package under C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
If my file name does not have any extension (e.g. foo ) then  "python foo" works. 
If I rename file from foo to foo.py then the "from .. import" statement to that package fails in foo.py:

```
try:
    from my_package.System.prefix import ...
except ImportError:
    print "ERROR: Could not import modules."
```

I have:
 PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages 
 Environment: Windows XP/ Python 2.7

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace, and the directory tree's layout of the package and module in question?

Comment: Sorry, I've used all my mana on mindreading already. You'll have to describe your actual setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild guess here: is your filename the same as the package that you're trying to import (`my_package` in your example)?

I was able to reproduce behavior similar to what you describe by creating a file, `django.py`, that contained the import statement `from django.db import models`.  When I ran `python django.py`, I got `ImportError: No module named db`.  When I moved code to a file named `django` (without a .py extension), deleted the `django.pyc` file, and ran `python django`, the import succeeded.

Why Python tries to import the `django` module, it starts by looking for a `django.py` file in the directory that contains the program being executed.  In the first case, it imports the `django.py` file that I created instead of the `django` module that's installed in `site-packages`.  In the second case, where I renamed my file `django`, Python can't find a `django.py` in the same directory as my file, so it properly import `django` from `site-packages`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly my case: filename = package name